# Have scrollDepth only activate if on mobile device

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use scrollDepth to trigger Google Analytic events when a user scrolls to a specific element on the page, however, I only want this to trigger on mobile. Some of the elements share the same id for Desktop.

Essentially, it should only send a scroll event if a user is on a mobile device, if they are on Desktop it will not send any scroll events.

This is what I assembled below, however, it doesn't seem to fire. Thoughts?

```
  jQuery(function() {
  jQuery.scrollDepth()
  });
  // Controls scroll-depth options
  jQuery.scrollDepth(function(e) {
  var scrollDepth = '(max-width: 600px)';
  if (window.matchMedia && window.matchMedia(scrollDepth).matches) {
  jQuery.scrollDepth({
    minHeight: 0,
    elements: ['.div1', '.div2', '.div3'],
    percentage: false,
    userTiming: false,
    pixelDepth: false,
    nonInteraction: false
  });
}
  else {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var width = $(window).width();
if (width <= 600)  {
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery.scrollDepth()
  });
}
  // Controls scroll-depth options
  jQuery.scrollDepth({
    minHeight: 0,
    elements: ['.div1', '.div2', '.div3'],
    percentage: false,
    userTiming: false,
    pixelDepth: false,
    nonInteraction: false
  });
```